# How to list Azure alerts that I created?

Tags: azure

How do I list the alert that only I created via Azure Portal ( via az cli is okay too). There are way too many alerts and I am unable to tell the ones that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No It's not possible. However you could use the filters to do the sorting. If you want to see the alerts created by you, you can navigate to **`Monitor - > Activity Log`** - > check for the column **`Event initiated by`**